# Hook declaration dependant on other values in declaration React radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a functionality similar to radio buttons. I want label A to always be the opposite of label B.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    { label: "a", prop: "a", checked: false },               // data[0] opposite of data[1]
    { label: "b", prop: "b", checked: false },               // data[1] opposite of data[2]
  ]);
```

Would it be possible to write something like this? :

```
label: "a", prop: "a", checked: !data[2].checked
```

I know I can use `setData({...data, changedValue})`, but I´d like to test other options.

Comment: If the two are always opposites, maybe that should be a single piece of state? E.g. `{ label: "a", prop: "a", checked: false, reverseLabel: "b", reverseProp: "b" }`?

Answer (score 2):

In your case each label has its own source of truth.

what if you make it like this:

```
const initialState = {
  labels : ["a","b"],
  checked: "a"
}

const [data,setData] = React.useState(initialState);
```

later in your code you can say

```
labels.map(val=>{
  //some random jsx
  return <Options checked={data.checked === val}/>
})
```